# Fitting Konva layer nodes into "viewport"

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

I am currently trying to create an algorithm that will center the viewport on the content present on the Stage.

[Lets say the stage is initiated and it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jb24.png)

[I can get it to this point where the stage is centred over all shapes on the stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxPXg.png)

[Now I need a way to figure out how far to zoom the stage so that none of the shapes are cut off by the "viewport"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGYEE.png)

Getting the origin/most central point in regards to every shape on the map is straight forward and I can get that far. I am having trouble figuring out a proper calculation to scale the stage such that each Shape on the stage is visible (plus some extra padding)

I am having a real tough time visualizing an answer mathematically in my head. The only solution I have came up was to create rectangles from the view and the objects on the stage and brute forcing an answer so that the edges of the view does not intersect any shapes on the stage.

Any guidance would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use something like this:

```
// do we need padding?
const padding = 10;

// get bounding rectangle
const box = layer.getClientRect({ relativeTo: stage });
const scale = Math.min(
  stage.width() / (box.width + padding * 2),
  stage.height() / (box.height + padding * 2)
);


stage.setAttrs({
  x: -box.x * scale + padding * scale,
  y: -box.y * scale  + padding * scale,
  scaleX: scale,
  scaleY: scale
});
```

http://jsbin.com/kobilamoro/2/edit?js,output

Comment: A very elegant solution, seriously thank you! I will have to look at the source for layer.getClientRect({ relativeTo: stage }); as that was the key I was missing for sure. 


The next step for me will to be getting the elements centered in the canvas when the viewport is bigger. Seriously thanks again!

Comment: hey @lavtron thank you for the solution! Although this will left align the map inside the canvas always - is there a way to make it always center horizontally and vertically? Thanks in advanced

Comment: @stillfire than should be simple. Just fix calculation a bit.